# Odoo 8: How can I send context to python method?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to send context to python method.
In xml, I have this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id="view_mim_wizardfor" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mim.wizard.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <notebook position="before">
        <field name="entete"/>
        <field name="purchase_order_id" context="{'show_state': True}"/>
    </notebook>
            <group name="sale_total" position="after">
                <button name="action_mim_wizard" 
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in',('draft','sent'))]}" 
                    type="object" string="Ajout avancé" 
                    class="oe_link oe_edit_only"/>
            </group>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

and I python I have this :

```
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    res = []
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        _logger.info('==============context============================%s', context)
        name = record.name
        if context.get('show_state', False):
            name = '%s %s' % (name, record.state)
        res.append((record.id, name))
        _logger.info('==============name_get============================name_get==============')
    return res
```

I don't get the 'show_state' in context, I don't know why.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't that `context` is going to be passed when you search for record, it's only passed when you try to create a record in fly (using create and edit option for example).

Instead pass the context in the action of the menu that opens `sale.order` records. for example the menu of `Sales Orders` you should change the context of its action like this, same thing for any menu you want to have this behavior in it:

```
   <record id="sale.action_orders" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="context">{'show_state': True}</field>
   </record>
```

In this case when you search for any record in any many2one this key will be passed in the context and you should found in your method.

Comment: In previous versions of Odoo it was possible to pass a context to a field in XML and receive it in methods like an `onchange` of this field, for example. Now this option disappeared and we have to write the context in the action. But this is worse since the action context is removed when refreshing the browser. Do you know if there is another way to pass a flag variable from a XML view to a Python method?

Comment: I've just checked that passing a context to a XML field and receive it in for example `onchange` methods actually works in Odoo 13, my view just was not refreshed well.

Comment: In onchange method yes, but is it passed even in the search call in m2o field?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are accessing this context on the purchase order (As per field **purchase_order_id**)

Try to check this, **self._context.get('show_state')**

Comment: I tried with self then changed it with record._context.get('show_state') but doesn't work.

Comment: can u check the 'purchase_order_id' field having the updated context? It seems your context is not updated properly.

Comment: the context is in the view when I check it throught debug mode > Edit form view

Comment: I will try to add it in act_window